# Find element in a page having multiple tabs

Tags: element

I have a website having a page containing multiple tabs
each tab is identified by cdk-step-content-0-1, cdk-step-content-0-2 and so on

please suggest me a good tutorial to create element by my own using hierarchy of pages and tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = document.getElementById("cdk-step-content-0-1")
```

The variable element will contain tab element.
You can find the parent or tabs wrapper element with element.parentElement.

Comment: Thanks Akif - I'm creating an object in same manner but  I'm not able to get dropdown after using the object.